# Playwright tests are not running when using playwright-extra

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I have E2E tests written in Playwright. Lately, I had issues with the captcha in the login flow so to pass it I installed playwright-extra.
It kind of worked - now the tester user succeeding in logging in and the setup is passing, but the tests are not running - this is the error I get:

```
Playwright Test did not expect test() to be called here.
Most common reasons include:

- You are calling test() in a configuration file.
- You are calling test() in a file that is imported by the configuration file.
- You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens
  when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.
```

This is my setup code

```
import { FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import LoginPage from '../pages/login.page';
import logger from '../../util/logger';
import { chromium } from 'playwright-extra';
import pluginStealth from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth"

const urlRegex = /(www|http:|https:)+\[^\\s\]+\[\\w\]/;

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
logger.info('Starting global setup');
const {
storageState,
headless: isHeadless,
trace,
baseURL,
} = config.projects\[0\].use;

const shouldTrace = trace === 'on' || trace === 'retain-on-failure';
const storageStatePath = storageState as string;

logger.info('Getting storageState via the UI');
chromium.use(pluginStealth())
const browser = await chromium.launch({
headless: isHeadless,
});
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
if (shouldTrace) await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });
try {
const login = new LoginPage(page);
await login.loginWithGoogle(isHeadless, baseURL);
await page.context().storageState({ path: storageState as string });
} catch (e) {
logger.error('Failed to set storageState', e);
throw e;
} finally {
if (shouldTrace) await context.tracing.stop({ path: 'results/globalTrace.zip' });
await browser.close();
logger.info('Done with getting storageState via the UI');
}

logger.info('Done with global setup');
}

export default globalSetup;
```

And this is one of the tests

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import AssetManagementPage from '../../pages/inventory.page';
import addXrayMetadata from '../../../util/upload-results/xrayMetadata';
import Network from '../../components/Network';


test('Inventory user should be able to switch table @smoke @monitoring ', async ({
  page,
}, testInfo) => {
  const testDescription = `GIVEN the inventory page
        WHEN I switch the table
        THEN expect the active table to update`;
  Network.listenToFailedResponseEvent(page, true);
  const inventoryPage = new AssetManagementPage(page);
  await inventoryPage.defaultPageInit();
  await expect(inventoryPage.loadedState).toBeVisible();
  await inventoryPage.switchTable('Events');
});
```

Any idea how can I solve it?

In `playwright.config.ts` I've added the line `testMatch: /.*.spec.ts/` but it didn't solve it